# SharePoint Web Service UpdateListItems Task Attachement

Tags: sharepoint

I'm currently using the SharePoint Web Service in order to create update or delete Tasks. To do so I use the method UpdateListItems with the according XML. This works fine for every text field, but I'm wondering if it is possible to add a an Attachment to a task which such method.

I found some post using the GetListItems in order to retrieve the attachments, but I didn't find a way to create it. If you have any idea, it will be usefull.

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like this was covered here pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334695/sharepoint-how-to-add-an-attachment-to-a-list-item-programatically

Comment: @ironman99: that question covers attachments using the object model, while this question is asking how to do it through web services.

Comment: Can you past any of your code that you've tried so far?

Comment: I found finally the answer [there][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100157/add-attachment-with-updatelistitems